# Site not serving media files but serving static files correctly

Tags: python, django, apache

I have a Django site in production. Static files are being served fine, but media files are failing to be retrieved.

my setting.py :

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = "media/"
```

I tried with both `"/media/"` and `"media/"`, first ones url is shown incorrectly in the HTML when using the `.url` attribute.

My Apache config:

```
Alias /static/ /var/www/MySite/static/
<Directory /var/www/MySite/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /media/ /var/www/MySite/media/
<Directory /var/www/MySite/media>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

In the view I retrieve as follows:

```
{% for photo in photos %}
        <div class="col-md-3 photo-wrapper">
            <img src="{{ photo.image.url }}"/>
        </div>
{% endfor %}
```

and URL gets generated as `http://mysite.co.za/media/profile_photos/photo.png`

Files do get uploaded as I can see them on the VPS Server, but when retrieving it fails, throwing a 404 not found.

It does work in Debug mode because I have the following in my urls.py

```
+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

but this does not work when debug mode is off. How would I go about serving these media files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure `/var/www/MySite/media` is your media directory?

Maybe you confuse the staticfiles (which are collected by the `collectstatic` command) with the mediafiles, which are saved by users of the webapp.

Looking at your settings, I believe your apache configuration should serve
`PROJECT_ROOT + '/media'`.

Or, you change your settings file so that `MEDIA_ROOT = /var/www/MySite/media`

Comment: My gosh, after so much trouble you are right, I wasn't thinking about the fact that you do a collectstatic to serve the static files, so my media files were next to my static files instead of in my root directory where Apache was looking for them. Thank you!